# Entity Framework with multiple databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Is there anyway to map multiple SQL Server databases in a single EF context? For instance I'm trying to do something like this

```
select order from context.Orders
where context.Users.Any(user => user.UserID == order.UserID)
```

And I'd like to get generated SQL along the lines of:

```
select .. from store.dbo.order where userID in 
(select userID from authentication.dbo.user)
```

and note that the database names are different - store in one place, authentication in the other.

I've found a few articles that deal with multiple schema ('dbo' in this case), but none dealing with multiple database names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a potential workaround, you could create a view of the table from the second database in the first database and point your mappings to the view.

Comment: Yeah, I would just do a view that links in the tables from the other database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible.  The context derives from [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

> A DbContext instance represents a combination of the Unit Of Work and Repository patterns such that it can be used to query from **a database** and group together changes that will then be written back to the store as a unit. DbContext is conceptually similar to ObjectContext.

Configuration (connection string, schema, etc) for a DbContext is specific to a single database.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. A notion of context is below notion of a database, and allowing this would probably be a bad practice. Allowing such a thing could cause developers to forget that they are dealing with two databases, and to take care about all performance implications that come from that.

I imagine you should still be able use two contexts and write elegant code.

```
var userIds = AuthContext.Users
    .Where(user => user.Name = "Bob")
    .Select(user => user.UserId)
    .ToList();

var orders = StoreContext.Orders
    .Where(order => userIds.Contains(order.UserId))
    .ToList()
```

First execute query on authentication database context, in order to provide parameters for second query.

Comment: FYI - I tried your suggestion out and got the following error: "The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts."

There are quite a few stackoverflow items for that error - all indicating that you can't mix contexts inside a single LINQ, and that you need to separate the queries, and pass an ienumerable from the first query results to the second.

Comment: Principle remains the same. Separate this query in two parts (first retrieving IDs, and then querying over it)

Comment: But that did make me wonder if the type of database separation we have is a bad practice or not. We have databases separated by product silo - but we also have common concerns (like users and authorizations) in yet a different database but the same database instance, with the intent to share that info with the various product silos. You can write a single SQL query that spans the databases, so I expected similar functionality in EF, and I'm really surprised that EF doesn't support it.

Comment: I'm not a specialist for database design, but I think that for such separation of concerns database schemas were intended. Not to say that separating databases is a bad design, but each approach has it's bad side. I don't take allowing a single database to be fault for green field projects, but I can imagine it's frustrating for you.

Comment: fyi - I tried to upvote you but I don't have sufficient stackoverflow reputation yet.